# CDK deploy Gatsby site exceeds 50 routing rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gatsby, aws-cdk

Trying to deploy a Gatsby site with AWS CDK but the BucketDeployment always fails the error message:

```
CREATE_FAILED | Custom::CDKBucketDeployment | DeploySiteCustomResourceE47C9748 Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: Command '['/opt/awscli/aws', 's3', 'cp', 's3://cdk-xxxXXXXX-assets-xxx/assets/xxxXXXXXXXX.zip', '/tmp/tmpXXX/XXXXX']' died with <Signals.SIGKILL: 9>
```

The size of the file is only 163MB so does not exceed the 500MB limit.

Using the gatsby-plugin-s3 I was able to get an error to say that the site had more than 50 routing rules.

How can I get around this with the CDK? I have tried using website-redirect-location but that isn't working either.

**bucket deployment**

```ts
const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, "Testbucket", {
  bucketName: "my-test-bucket",
  publicReadAccess: true,
  removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
  websiteIndexDocument: "index.html"
});

new s3Deploy.BucketDeployment(this, "DeploySite", {
  sources: [s3Deploy.Source.asset("../gatsby-site/public")],
  destinationBucket: bucket,
  metadata: { "website-redirect-location": "index.html"}
});
```

Comment: What's the error message in CloudFormation? Maybe the size is too big.

Comment: I have updated the question with more info and where I tried using metadata

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lambda responsible for unzipping the archive and copying the contents to the destination crashed because it ran out of memory.

Increase its memory with [`memoryLimit`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3_deployment.BucketDeployment.html#memorylimit) when creating your `BucketDeployment` construct. By default, the lambda gets 128MB of memory, which is insufficient in your case.